# Class not registered VBA excel

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to copy slides from one PowerPoint presentation to another with the use of a VBA script in excel. Found the below code but when trying to run it I receive the following error
[image]

I'm working on 64 bit machine and I'm using the following references:
-Visual Basic For Applications
-Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library
-OLE Automation
-Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Libarary
-Microsoft PowerPoint 16.0 Object Library

```
Dim objPresentation As Presentation
Dim i As Integer

'open the target presentation
Set objPresentation = Presentations.Open("C:\Users\john\Desktop\123.pptx")
For i = 1 To objPresentation.Slides.Count
    objPresentation.Slides.Item(i).Copy
    Presentations.Item(1).Slides.Paste
    Presentations.Item(1).Slides.Item(Presentations.Item(1).Slides.Count).Design = _
        objPresentation.Slides.Item(i).Design
Next i
objPresentation.Close
End Sub
```

Could someone please help me overcome this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have not declared a Powerpoint application object.

```
Dim objPowerPoint As New PowerPoint.Application
Dim objPresentation As Presentation
Dim i As Integer

'open the target presentation
Set objPresentation = objPowerPoint.Presentations.Open("C:\Users\john\Desktop\123.pptx")

'~~> Rest of the code
```

Comment: Lets say there is some progress yet the same error still exists. It has moved from line: Set objPresentation = Presentations.Open("C:\Users\john\Desktop\123.pptx") to Presentations.Item(1).Slides.Paste

Comment: Yes of course. I thought you would understand the concept. `objPowerPoint.Presentations.Item(1)...`

Comment: My apologies I'm completely new at this, now I get it fixed the rest and it works. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Working code below

```
Sub Example2()
Dim objPowerPoint As New PowerPoint.Application
Dim objPresentation As Presentation
Dim i As Integer

'open the target presentation
Set objPresentation = objPowerPoint.Presentations.Open("C:\Users\john\Desktop\p123.pptx")
For i = 1 To objPresentation.Slides.Count
    objPresentation.Slides.Item(i).Copy
    objPowerPoint.Presentations.Item(1).Slides.Paste
    objPowerPoint.Presentations.Item(1).Slides.Item(objPowerPoint.Presentations.Item(1).Slides.Count).Design = _
        objPresentation.Slides.Item(i).Design
Next i
objPresentation.Close
End Sub
```